# Magento2 : How to get product custom option Title from its ID

Tags: magento2, custom-options, title

In a magento2 plugin I would like to get the product custom options title from the option ID, but I do not know what injection to make in the constructor and what functions to use to achieve that...

```
$option_id=13;
$option_Title=$this->..->getTitle($option_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with collection, my solution:

```
protected $_storeManager;
protected $_options;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\Option\CollectionFactory $options,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $_storeManager
    ){
    $this->_storeManager = $_storeManager;
    $this->_options = $options;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function getOption($optionId){
    return $this->appendSelections(
        $this->_options->create()
        ->addFieldToFilter('option_id', $optionId)
        ->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', $this->getProduct()->getEntityId())
        ->joinValues($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()) // this will append title
        ->getFirstItem(),
        $this->getProduct()
    );
}
protected function appendSelections(\Magento\Bundle\Model\Option $option, $product){
    if($option->getOptionId()){
        $typeInstance = $product->getTypeInstance();
        $selections = $typeInstance->getSelectionsCollection([$option->getOptionId()], $product);
        $option->setData('selections', $selections);
    }
    return $option;
}
```

With "Repository":

```
$this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Bundle\Model\OptionRepository')->get(
    $productSku,
    $optionId
);
```

This solution for bundle options but in custom options will be similar...